# showing error when there is no data on 0 index

Tags: angularjs

Now in case of `reason` and `moveOutDate`, it is working fine but if there is no data on zero index in case of `note` then the code is breaking showing no data.

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'note' of undefined

```js
if (this.vacateStatus.moveOutDate) {
    this.intentToVacateForm.patchValue({
        reason: {
            id: this.vacateStatus.reason.id,
        },
        moveOutDate: {
            startDate: moment(this.vacateStatus.moveOutDate),
            endDate: moment(this.vacateStatus.moveOutDate)
        },
        note: {
            note: this.vacateStatus.note[0].note
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you get some error it's good to include error message in your question

Comment: sure, I will do that

Comment: If there is no data at Zero index try to handle that with validation.

Comment: not working with validation in because i am getting undefined at zero index

Comment: Can you post the data you are having?

Comment: "note":[  
         {  
            "id":22,
            "note":"urgent work",
            "properties":[  

            ],

So, the note key which comes under note object is dynamic. If I have not added note it won't show

Comment: Are you seeing the value of this.vacateStatus.note[0].note via console.log?

Comment: No not on console log. [object object ] is showing in input field

Comment: I'm pretty sure `this.vacateStatus.note[0].note` is insufficient in terms of depth, you shouldnt set the input field with an object.

Comment: <input [attr.disabled]="disableForm" autocomplete="off" formControlName="note" matInput> I have used this one

Comment: `this.vacateStatus.note[0].note` is an object. Please decide which of its property you want to display, and set `note` to this property.

Comment: @HelloWorld "note":[ { "id":22, "note":"urgent work", "properties":[ ] so on
this is the response i want to show note key in input field and that's what I am trrying to get. Although it works fine when I send some data but it gets break when i leave it empty.

Answer (score 0):

The error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'note' of undefined` means that `this.vacateStatus` is undefined and therefore `vacateStatus.note` cannot be accessed.

You can either change the first condition to check if vacateStatus exists

```
if (this.vacateStatus && this.vacateStatus.moveOutDate) {
```

Or where you access `note` instead of `note: this.vacateStatus.note[0].note` doing this:

```
note: this.vacateStatus && this.vacateStatus.note && this.vacateStatus.note.length > 0 && this.vacateStatus.note[0].note
```

Comment: code is working till this.vacateStatus.note.length > 0 but after that showing [object object ] in note

Comment: I think that is what you wanted. To get the note object. `[object object]` is just how it is printed to the console, you can use `JSON.stringify(something)` to output the whole content